# Icefaces RowSelector double-click

Tags: jsf, datatable, icefaces, double-click

I have a small problem with double-click handling with icefaces.

There are two methods of doing it, it seems.

SelectionListener => you know if it is a double click or not with the fired ClickActionEvent but you cannot navigate (open a new "details" page on a row double-click)

ClickAction => navigation OK, how do you know if it is a doulbe-click or not ?

What is the best way of doing what i want to achieve ? Say i have a list of persons, double click on a person should open a details page of that person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowSelector` tag which has attribute `clickListener`.

When a row is clicked `ClickActionEvent` is called & you can determine in backing bean, if its double-clicked or not by `ClickActionEvent.isDblClick()`.

For navigation, in backing bean action event

```
FacesContext context = PersistentFacesState.getInstance().getFacesContext();
NavigationHandler handler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
handler.handleNavigation(context, fromAction, outcome);
```

Can also try

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```